# Centrar los elemento de una lista en una barra de navegacion

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, spring, spring-boot

estoy haciendo una barra de navegación con Bootstrap, dentro del framework de Spring Boot, La cual les envió:

**HTML**

```
<header th:fragment="header">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
        <a class="navbar-brand text-white">SILOCK</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">

            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item active pull-right"><a class="nav-link text-white">
                        <span class="fa fa-home"></span> Inicio
                </a></li>

                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#about"
                    th:href="@{/}">Casillero</a></li>

                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#about"
                    th:href="@{/}">Compartimiento</a></li>

                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#about"
                    th:href="@{/}">Compartimiento-Empleado</a></li>

                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#about"
                    th:href="@{/}">Empleado</a></li>    

                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#about"
                    th:href="@{/}">Departamento</a></li>

                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#about"
                    th:href="@{/}">Empresa</a></li>

                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#about"
                    th:href="@{/}">Usuario</a></li>

                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#about"
                    th:href="@{/}">Rol</a></li>

                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#about"
                    th:href="@{/}">Perfil</a></li>

                    <li class="nav-item active pull-right"><a class="nav-link text-white">
                        <span class="fa fa-user"></span> Sesion
                </a></li>

                    </ul>
        </div>

    </nav>
</header>
```

**CSS:**

```
  body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    position: fixed;
}

 .navbar-nav {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
   background: #222222;
  }

  .navbar-nav > li {
      float: none;
      display: inline-block;
    }

.nav-item::after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 0px;
    height: 2px;
    background: #17a2b8;
    transition: 0.2s;
}

.nav-item:hover::after {
    width: 100%;
}

.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .active>.nav-link, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link.active,
    .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link.show, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .show>.nav-link,
    .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:focus, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover
    {
    color: white;
}

.nav-link {
    padding: 5px 15px;
    transition: 0.2s;
}
```

Ahora, vengo a pedirles que en mi barra de navegación deseo tener el `<li>inicio</li>` en la esquina izquierda, `<li>Sesión</li>` en la esquina derecha y `<li>Casillero</li>`, `<li>Compartimiento</li>`, `<li>Compartimiento-Empleado</li>`, `<li>Empleado</li>`, `<li>Departamento</li>`, `<li>Empresa</li>`, `<li>Usuario</li>`, `<li>Rol</li>` y <`li>Perfil</li>` centrado. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agrega una clase diferente a los dos elementos, inicio y sesión, dales un

```
.sesion{
text-align: right;
}
.inicio{
text-align: center;
}
```

o igualmente con un float ya sea right o center, acuerdate de agregar a los li

```
<li class="sesion">sesión</li>
```

Comment: Listo, muchas gracias, funciono tu idea.